# CSS Media query for visual impairments

Tags: css, media-queries, accessibility

Is there currently a way or perhaps a proposal, for a CSS media query that would allows designers to change up values for those with visual impairments (but not to the degree of needing a screen reader)?

There are media queries such as prefer-reduced-motion for folks with motion related issues, but I can't find anything that allows changes for vision related issues.

In particular it would be nice to be able to substitute a more legible font for a fancy font, when someone has vision issues:

```
body: {
  font-family: 'some-trendy-thin-font';
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media (prefers-vision-enhancements) {
  body: {
    font-family: 'Atkinson-Hyperlegible-Regular';
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

I know users can increase font size and/or magnify their screen, but even that doesn't solve everything when a designer uses an unusual font face.   Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the visual accessibility approach for the web is to make sure that the user can modify the appearance of your pages. Not develop alternative design.

A user who need specific font will override the font (for exemple with a web extension). It's not a good idea for accessibility to use too ununsual font. If it's the case, an alternative for the users who are not used to override font, is to have a font switch fonctionnality on your site.

However, you've got few media queries to adapt your design, depending on the user agent settings. For exemple :

- prefers-color-scheme : allow you to code a dark mode and light mode,
- forced-color : forced color mode is when user have their own colors (for text, background, etc.). For exemple : hight contrast mode in Windows. So you don't have to fully design this mode as the page will be render with the colors chosen by the user, but the media queries can be helpfull to fix few things (like increase border on a modal).